# AngularJS bind class attribute to model

Tags: angularjs

I have the following markup:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <label ng-repeat="role in roles">
        <div ng-class="{ big: selectedRoles }">
            <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="selectedRoles" checklist-value="role.id" />{{role.text}}</div>
    </label>
</div>
```

I need the class "big" to be set to checked items. The ng-class attribute is not working as expected. Replicated problem in http://jsfiddle.net/qky1ownh/1/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since selectedRoles is an array of role ids you could just use [array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find if it in the selected list:-

```
<div ng-class="{ big: selectedRoles.indexOf(role.id)+1 }">
```

Since `indexOf` returns the item's index in the array(zero-based) and -1 when not found just add-up 1 to make it falsy.

Or just add a method in your controller to keep out any logic from the view and the fact that controllers are better testable than template, do :

controller:-

```
$scope.hasRole = function(id){
  return $scope.selectedRoles.indexOf(id) > -1;
}
```

and use it in the view as:

```
<div ng-class="{ big: hasRole(role.id) }">
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to keep stuffing logic in your view, you could use an object literal to track the changes to the list instead.

```
$scope.selectedRoles = {
  1: true,
  2: true,
  4: true
};
```

It allows you to just use `ng-model` on your checkboxes as well instead of some funky checkbox-list/value type stuff:

```
<div ng-class="{ big: selectedRoles[role.id] }">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedRoles[role.id]" />{{role.text}}
</div>
```

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qky1ownh/8/

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to apply a selected property to the object.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7kfum1uu/

```
<div ng-class="{ 'big': role.selected }">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="role.selected">{{role.text}}
</div>
```

Comment: This would be the best approach if OP has the flexibility to have a merged data coming back. However possibility that data may be coming from different sources OP may have to do extra work mapping from source and map it back on save.  Regardless +1 for you...